# SQL - order by varchar columns

Tags: sql

I have a table containing a varchar column for months.
Because of some reasons I have to save Persian months in it like Farvardin , Ordibehesh , ... .
Now I want to select some rows from that table and I want to order my rows by months.
what should I do ?
Please just use SQL commands.

Comment: Make a table with `[monthname, monthnumber]` `join` it and `order by monthnumber`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a custom sort order with:

```
SELECT *
FROM months
ORDER BY CASE
          WHEN monthName = 'Farvardin' THEN '1'
          WHEN monthName = 'Ordibehesh' THEN '2'
          ...
          ELSE monthName END ASC
```